# cx_Freeze '@rpath/libQtDeclarative.4.dylib': doesn't exist or not a regular file

Tags: macos, python-2.7, qt4, pyqt4, cx-freeze

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need
# fine tuning.
buildOptions = dict(packages = ["idna","lib","gui","plugins"], excludes = ["Tcl","tcl"]

import sys
base = 'Win32GUI' if sys.platform=='win32' else None

executables = [
Executable('electrum-xvg', base=base, targetName = 'Electrum XVG',icon="electrum.icns")]

setup(name='electrum-xvg',
  version = '1.0',
  description = '',
  options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
  executables = executables])
```

I have the above setup.py file which I am using to try build application on OSX Sierra. But when I use `python setup.py bdist_mac` it raises error

```
@rpath/libQtDeclarative.4.dylib
error: can't copy '@rpath/libQtDeclarative.4.dylib': doesn't exist or not a regular file
```

`libQtDeclarative.4.dylib` is present in `~/anaconda/envs/pyqtapp/lib` on my system but when I used `otool -D libQtDeclarative.4.dylib` it raised error that no such file exists, so I used

```
install_name_tool -id "@rpath/libQtDeclarative.4.dylib" libQtDeclarative.4.dylib
```

in `~/anaconda/envs/pyqtapp/lib` now when I run `otool -D libQtDeclarative.4.dylib` I get

```
libQtDeclarative.4.dylib:
@rpath/libQtDeclarative.4.dylib
```

but cx_Freeze still raises the error

```
error: can't copy '@rpath/libQtDeclarative.4.dylib': doesn't exist or not a regular file
```

Comment: where is your includes declaration?

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly setting includes (list of relative paths):

```
includefiles = ['README.txt', 'CHANGELOG.txt', 'helpers\uncompress\unRAR.exe', , 'helpers\uncompress\unzip.exe']
```